# Load different Database Symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, environment-variables

How can I load different database for production and development environment ?

In parameters.yml I have the main database configuration, but I don't know how to add the dev database with differets parameters.

I'm looking for this on Google but I can't find any help.

Maybe with config_dev.yml and config_prod.yml? but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do something like this:

Files hierarchy:
1) `parameters.yml` - for common parameters
2) create `parameters_dev.yml` - only dev db connection params
3) create `parameters_prod.yml` - only prod db connection params

In head of config files:
1) `config.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

2) `config_dev.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_dev.yml }
```

3) `config_prod.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_prod.yml}
```

Comment: can you show a detailed version of this with where you actually put the parameters for the database in particular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) to store environment-specific (or system-specific) variables easily.

For example, in a `config/parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    parameter_name: some_value
```

In `config.yml`, at the top:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

Then, you can substitute a parameter using the syntax `"%parameter_name%"` where the variable's value should appear.